# Gnuplot - a way to convert and plot text information?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot to display the information contained in a **file** as in the example below:

```
    1           2                   3                   …   10    11
    1           1.0000000e-06       1.0000000e-06       …   0 
    2           2.5000000e-06       1.5000000e-06       …   0     #dt_grow
    3           4.7500000e-06       2.2500000e-06       …   0     #dt_grow
    4           8.1250000e-06       3.3750000e-06       …   0     #dt_cfl
    5           1.2450703e-05       4.3257029e-06       …   1     #dt_mach, max_iteration_turbulence
    6           1.6811013e-05       0.3603104e-06       …   0     #dt_grow
```

My **goal** is to be able to represent, somehow, the information listed in *column 11* which, as you can see, contains non-numeric characters.

It might be pointless but, before moving ahead, it might be helpful to stress that:

1. row1 has no value at column 11
2. each column 11 value start with # and is not quoted
3. column 11 contains many other different possible entries (e.g. "#dt_piso","#dt_piso, 2*max_piso reached", "#dt_mach, temperature extrapolation error")
4. when values of column 11 present an additional information (e.g ", max_iteration_turbulence") values of column 10 are non-zero
5. the number of rows is typically of the order 10^6

My **idea** was to use associate a numeric value to each element of column11 using functions (e.g. if #dt_grow then 1, if #dt_cfl then 2 ecc) so that I can somehow represent this information.

**What I have tried** so far produce nothing but errors (that I am for brevity listing below each used plot command):

```
p "file" u 1:11 w l
--> x range is invalid

p "file" u 1:(''.$11 eq "#dt_cfl" ? 1 : 0) w l
--> warning: Skipping data file with no valid points. x range is invalid

p "file" u 1:(column(11) eq "#dt_cfl" ? 1 : 0) w l
--> internal error : STRING operator applied to non-STRING type

p "file" u 1:(strcol(11) eq "#dt_cfl" ? 1 : 0) w l
--> internal error : STRING operator applied to non-STRING type

splot "time.out" u 1:(11 eq "#dt_cfl" ? 1 : 0) w l
--> Need 1 or 3 columns for cartesian data

#Usage of functions does not resolve the issue:
e.g. f(x)= ''.x eq "#dt_cfl" ? 1 : 0
```

As you can probably tell by the diversity of my trials I am somehow confused on how it is recommendable to proceed in such cases. I have never had to plot string data and I am not quite sure of what is causing the issue. I've been looking for some inputs on the documentation but nothing really helped me on this. I would very much appreciate any inputs on **how to handle string data and associate them to numeric values**.

**To wrap it up**: I want to display the evolution of the information on column 11.
Ideally, I would like to be able to use the eventual additional information (as explained in point 4 above) based on the value of column 10.

Based on my request I believe a python script could better fit my necessities, but I am wondering if gnuplot offers such possibilities and I am eager to learn more.

Thanks in advance :)!

**P.S.:** I am adding a sketch of the results I am trying to obtain hping that this can help clarify my goals.
I am anyway open to new solution as this is just *my* plan of how I was thinking about overcoming the problem of plotting text data.
With respect to the few rows of data that provided above and assuming to do the following assosiations:

- #dt_grow is 1
- #dt_cfl  is 2
- #dt_mach is 3
- so on for other possible values (this could be hardcoded as I would have no more that 10 possible values in column11)

[Plot_ sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuw7c.png)

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can do it with gnuplot. Where do you want to display this text information? At some specific x,y value or at the x-value and the border of the graph?

Comment: This is an output file of a CFD simulation that provides specific information (c11) on the status at each iteration (c1). In general, I use gnuplot to monitor how quantities evolves to keep track of the simulation and I would like to add this info to my monitors. I'd like to have a 2Dplot displaying info of c11 (y-axis) against c1 values.

Since I can't plot text values in a 2D representation, I'm trying to associate a specific numeric value to each possible value of column 11 (e.g. #dt_cfl is 1, #dt_mach is 2...) and use this in a 2D plot that would allow me to follow how column 11 evolves.

Comment: How many iterations do you typically have? And how many different possible values in column11, about 10, 20 or 50? You could also place a label (i.e. col11 value) at x=col1="iteration number" and e.g. y=col2="deviation or whatever". Would this help? Maybe you can add a freehand sketch to illustrate your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
You can use the 11th column (here: 5th column) as x2ticlabels (check `help xticlabels`). Before, link the `x2` axis to the `x1` axis (check `help link`).
You could rotate the x2tic labels if they are getting to many and overlap: `set x2tics rotate by 90`.
In principle, you could get rid of the leading `#` of each label, but I guess it will get a bit tricky because of your missing value in row 1.
Look at the example below as a starting point.

**Script:**

```
### adding text info from columns to some labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
    1   2               3               4     5
    1   1.0000000e-06   1.0000000e-06   0
    2   2.5000000e-06   1.5000000e-06   0     #dt_grow
    3   4.7500000e-06   2.2500000e-06   0     #dt_grow
    4   8.1250000e-06   3.3750000e-06   0     #dt_cfl
    5   1.2450703e-05   4.3257029e-06   1     #dt_mach, max_iteration_turbulence
    6   1.6811013e-05   0.3603104e-06   0     #dt_grow
EOD

set termoption noenhanced
set key top left 
set link x2 via x inverse x
set x2tics

plot $Data u 1:2:x2tic(5) skip 1 axes x2y1 w lp pt 7 lc "red"       title "column 2", \
        '' u 1:3          skip 1           w lp pt 7 lc "web-green" title "column 3"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

I guess I understand what you want to do but the background is still a bit unclear.
What you are asking for is a conversion or mapping of strings to numbers.
I assume you have a fixed and known set of keywords.
Apparently, for your desired plot the other columns besides 1 and 11 do not play a role.
Your missing value in column 11 in row 1 (excl. header) will create problems, hence add the option `skip 2`.
In the minimized example below, your column 11 is actually column 2.
The example below will create some random test data for better illustration.

- create a string list of your keywords
- you can address them via `word()`, check `help word`
- you can (mis)use `sum` for a lookup to get the index, check `help sum`
- furthermore, check `help strcol`, `help xticlabels`, `help skip`, `help ternary`.

**Script:**

```
### map strings to numbers
reset session

myKeys   = '#dt_grow #dt_cfl #dt_piso #dt_foo #dt_bar #dt_xyz #dt_abc'
myKey(i) = word(myKeys,i)

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 50
    plot '+' u ("1 2") every ::0::0 w table
    plot '+' u ("1")   every ::0::0 w table
    plot '+' u ($0+1):(word(myKeys,int(rand(0)*words(myKeys)+1))) w table
unset table

getIdx(s) = (n=0, sum[i=1:words(myKeys)] (s eq myKey(i) ? n=i : 0), n)
set ytics 1
set grid x,y

plot $Data u 1:(y0=getIdx(strcol(2))):ytic(myKey(y0)) skip 2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I really appreciated the speed, detail and clarity of your reply and I apologise for coming back to this topic so late. I'd also like to thank you for your topic suggestions. 
This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!
Unfortunately, on the cluster I'm using v4.6 is provided which is incompatible with both `skip` and `pseudo-column #$` (as alternatively proposed by @Ethan).
It is not the most elegant solution, but manually deleting the first row before plotting solves the problem and I can live with that.

Many thanks again!

Comment: @Salvatore I'm pretty sure there is a workaround for gnuplot4.6., e.g. `skip 2` can be replaced by `every ::1`. So, if my second script would do the job, if you want I can think about a gnuplot 4.6.0 version. But it's still not clear to me what you want to see as output.

Comment: Just tried out `every ::1`, it works just fine. Super!
I am sorry if I generated some confusion on my aim, but again, the plot you presented here is exactly what I was looking for!

Also, there was actually no need for me to present all the other columns in the first place as I was just concerned with column 1 and 11. I will note this for future questions.

Thanks again for your precious support!

Comment: @Salvatore glad to hear. If your problem is solved, please select the accept check mark (and helpful mark if you have >=15 reputation) at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered.

Comment: still didn't earn this feature. This was indeed my first question on stack overflow. I will make sure to accept it as soon as I gain this feature. This answer deserve it :)!

Comment: @Salvatore you can't upvote until you get 15 reputation. But you can _always_ accept an answer. There is a check mark on the top left of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I will not attempt a full answer right now, but here are a few pieces that may be useful by themselves or in conjunction with the answer from @theozh.

- **Column 11 not always present**: The presence or absence of column 11 on any given line can be tested using the "pseudo-column" `#$`, which evaluates to the total number of columns found on that line.  See "help pseudo".  This feature was introduced in gnuplot version 5.4.2 (June 2021). For example to plot the values of column 10 but only if column 11 is also present:

  ```
  plot FOO using 0:((#$ > 10) ? column(10) : NaN)
  ```

-**Separate lines on the graph for each column 11 category**: This could be done more cleanly using arrays in the development version of gnuplot, but sticking with features present in version 5.4 I suggest placing all the categories you want to track in one big string and then looping over the string.

```
Category = "#dt_grow #dt_cfl #dt_mach"
xcoord(x) = ... some function of the value in column 1? ...
ycoord(y) = ... some function of the value in column 10? ...
set datafile missing NaN #ignore any lines that evaluate to NaN

plot for [cat in Category] (xcoord($1)) : (strcol(#$) eq cat ? ycoord($10) : NaN) with steps
```

Comment: The use of `pseudo-column #$` sounds like an elegant solution to the problem of missing entries here and there in column 11.
I can not use that though as the gnuplot version provided on the cluster I am using is not compatible with that.
Thanks anyway, this might be very useful for someone else!